# Locate a cell among several tables then increment that cell's value by 1

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

This is a simplified version of the problem using only 2 tables. My actual setup has 8 tables, but I'm sure I can expand a concept that works with 2 tables to make it work with 8.

The situation:

- There are two separate tables with similar content. Example given further on.
- Each is structured as a named table in Excel (Table901 and Table902) with column headers.
- Each has 2 columns of relevant data: ID and Mark.
- 1st column: unique numeric ID code. Table901[ID].
- 2nd column: positive whole number value assigned to that code. Table901[Mark].
- Cell Q43 has a value in it that should match an ID in one of the tables. Q43 would be changed to a new ID before each use of this macro.

The challenge:
I want a macro that will look at the value in cell Q43, locate the matching ID across all tables, and increment the corresponding Mark value by 1.

Example:
I want to start with something like this:

```
|   Table901   |   |    Table902  |   | Cell Q43 |
|  ID   | Mark |   |  ID   | Mark |   |   57551  |
| 84234 |   5  |   | 67485 |  15  |
| 45731 |  17  |   | 98431 |   3  |
| 74693 |  12  |   | 57551 |  10  |
```

And activate the macro to get this:

```
|   Table901   |   |    Table902  |   | Cell Q43 |
|  ID   | Mark |   |  ID   | Mark |   |   57551  |
| 84234 |   5  |   | 67485 |  15  |
| 45731 |  17  |   | 98431 |   3  |
| 74693 |  12  |   | 57551 |  11  |
```

Where the value in the Mark column corresponding to the ID in Q43 has been incremented by 1.

I've been mulling this problem over for a couple years, trying out various formulas for returning a cell address in one table, or a value from the Mark column on any table, but I haven't figured out how to implement any of it in a macro.

The closest I've come is using this formula in a random cell in the sheet (cell V43) to get the intended Mark value:
=FILTER(Table901[Mark],Table901[ID]=Q43,FILTER(Table902[Mark],Table902[ID]=Q43))+1

In the example tables above, this would search through the first table, fail to find the ID specified in Q43, continue by searching the second table, successfully find the ID, note that the corresponding Mark value is 10, increment it by 1, and return 11.

However, as convenient as that formula is at locating the exact Mark value I want among multiple tables and performing the increment, it just gives me that new value in whichever cell I have the formula in. I still have to locate the correct cell myself and enter the new value. As I'm sure you can guess, the "+1" part isn't the hard part, it's the "find the correct cell" part that can get difficult when there are potentially thousands of entries across multiple tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by looping through the two tables on the active sheet using VBA. The logic can be easily extended to validate all tables on all worksheet.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim sId, arr, oTab As ListObject
    Dim c As Range, i As Long
    sId = [Q43]
    For Each oTab In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
        If oTab.Name = "Table901" Or oTab.Name = "Table902" Then
            arr = oTab.DataBodyRange.Value
            For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
                If arr(i, 1) = sId Then
                    With oTab.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 2)
                        .Value = .Value + 1
                    End With
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Increment in Matching Rows of Excel Tables

[image]

```vb
Sub IncrementMarks()

    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const MARK_TITLE As String = "Mark"
    Const ID_TITLE As String = "ID"
    Const ID_CELL As String = "Q43"
    Const INCREMENT As Long = 1
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim ID As Variant: ID = ws.Range(ID_CELL).Value
    
    Dim lo As ListObject, ilc As ListColumn, irg As Range, iCell As Range
    Dim mCell As Range, ColumnOffset As Long, FirstRow As Long
    
    For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
        Set ilc = lo.ListColumns(ID_TITLE)
        ColumnOffset = lo.ListColumns(MARK_TITLE).Index - ilc.Index
        Set irg = ilc.DataBodyRange
        Set iCell = irg.Find(ID, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not iCell Is Nothing Then
            FirstRow = iCell.Row
            Do
                Set mCell = iCell.Offset(, ColumnOffset)
                mCell.Value = mCell.Value + INCREMENT
                Set iCell = irg.FindNext(iCell)
            Loop Until iCell.Row = FirstRow
        End If
    Next lo
        
    MsgBox "The marks of ID """ & ID & """ were incremented by " & INCREMENT _
        & ".", vbInformation
        
End Sub
```

Comment: I set up a test workbook (called TestBook.xlsm) with the test tables I put in the example, with the ID cell for comparison changed to G1 instead of Q43, then created your macro. Unfortunately I can't seem to get past the Dim wb as Workbook line without an Error 424 - Object Required.

This is the updated line with the name of the workbook. I've tried with and without the file extension, neither works.

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = TestBook.xlsm

Answer (score 0):

Insert this in a standard module.

```
Sub FindIt()
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) '<~~ change this number if this is not the first worksheet
    Set rngFound = ws.Range("A1:B2").Find(ws.Range("Q43"), , xlValues, xlWhole) '<~~ change "A1:B2" to the range of the tables you are searching into
    If rngFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Q43 cell value not found."
    Else
        rngFound.Offset(0, 1) = rngFound.Offset(0, 1) + 1
    End If
End Sub
```